# owl url hash navigation wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, owl-carousel

I am trying to add `OwlCarousel2` Url Hash Navigation to wordpress by echoing  out my div, but there's wordpress function and I don't really know how to handle it with my echo

Here's my code :

```
<div id="owl-main" class="owl-hash">
       <?php $feat_query = new WP_Query( array( 'showposts' => 5,'meta_key'=>'_thumbnail_id') ); ?>
        <?php  if ( $feat_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $feat_query->have_posts() ) {
        $feat_query->the_post(); 
        $counter = 1;
        $counter++;
        $permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);
        echo'<div class="item" data-hash='.$counter.'<a href=.'$permalink'.'>'<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>';}
        {
        echo'<a class="button<?php echo $counter?>" href= "#<?php echo $counter;?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>';
         }

} // end if?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you want to get, but try like this:

```
<div id="owl-main" class="owl-hash">
    <?php $counter = 1; ?>
    <?php $feat_query = new WP_Query( array( 'showposts' => 5,'meta_key'=>'_thumbnail_id') ); ?>
    <?php
    if ( $feat_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $feat_query->have_posts() ) {
            $feat_query->the_post();
            $permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);
            echo '<div class="item" data-hash="'.$counter.'"><a href="'.$permalink.'">'. get_the_post_thumbnail() . get_the_title().'</a></div>';
            $counter++;
        }
        echo '<a class="button '.$counter.'" href="#'.$counter.'">'.get_the_title().'</a>';
    } // end if?>
</div>
```

You have echo, then `php` tags already in the `php` environment. And multiple echos. That's not good.

Install SublimeText 3, and you'll see when you write your code by the coloring. If the coloring is off, you know something is wrong.

For instance, my code looks like this:

[image]

Whereas yours looks like this

[image]

You can clearly see the variables in green, functions in orange and html in blue. In your case even the `php` code is in blue (not good).

Also I reorganized your code a bit. You should move your initializing counter variable outside of the loop, otherwise it will always be set to 1 in the while, and you won't get any counting done. Also I didn't test this, so it may turn out that you'd have to use `the_post_thumbnail()` instead of `get_the_post_thumbnail()` (`get_` functions are usually used in the `return` environment, rather then `echo`). But try it out and see if it works.

**EDITED CODE**

So if you put it like this

```
<div id="owl-main" class="owl-hash">
    <?php $counter = 1; ?>
    <?php $feat_query = new WP_Query( array( 'showposts' => 5,'meta_key'=>'_thumbnail_id') ); ?>
    <?php
    if ( $feat_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $feat_query->have_posts() ) {
            $feat_query->the_post();
            $permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);
            echo '<div class="item" data-hash="'.$counter.'"><a href="'.$permalink.'">'. get_the_post_thumbnail() . get_the_title().'</a></div>';
            echo '<a class="button '.$counter.'" href="#'.$counter.'">'.get_the_title().'</a>';
            $counter++;
        }
    } // end if
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</div>
```

You'd get a code that looks like this:

```
<div id="owl-main" class="owl-hash">
    <div class="item" data-hash="1">
        <a href="http://yoursite.com/?p=98">
            <img width="825" height="510" src="http://yoursite.com/wp-content/uploads/image1.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="Image 1">
            Image post 1
        </a>
    </div>
    <a class="button 1" href="#1">Image post 1</a>
    <div class="item" data-hash="2">
        <a href="http://yoursite.com/?p=95">
            <img width="825" height="510" src="http://yoursite.com/wp-content/uploads/image2.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="Image 2">
            Image post 2
        </a>
    </div>
    <a class="button 2" href="#2">Image post 2</a>
    <div class="item" data-hash="3">
        <a href="http://yoursite.com/?p=93">
            <img width="825" height="510" src="http://yoursite.com/wp-content/uploads/image3.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="Image 3">
            Image post 3
        </a>
    </div>
    <a class="button 3" href="#3">Image post 3</a>
    <div class="item" data-hash="4">
        <a href="http://yoursite.com/?p=91">
            <img width="825" height="510" src="http://yoursite.com/wp-content/uploads/image4.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="Image 4">
            Image post 4
        </a>
    </div>
    <a class="button 4" href="#4">Image post 4</a>
    <div class="item" data-hash="5">
        <a href="http://yoursite.com/?p=89">
            <img width="825" height="510" src="http://yoursite.com/wp-content/uploads/image5.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="Image 5">
            Image post 5
        </a>
    </div>
    <a class="button 5" href="#5">Image post 5</a>
</div>
```

I tested it and it works.

**NEW CODE**

Based on your last code I think you meant something like this:

```
<section>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div  class="owl-hash">
            <?php $counter = 1; ?>
            <?php $feat_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 5,'meta_key'=>'_thumbnail_id') ); ?>
            <?php
            if ( $feat_query->have_posts() ) {
                while ( $feat_query->have_posts() ) {
                    $feat_query->the_post();
                    $permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);
                    echo '<div class="item" data-hash="'.$counter.'"><a href="'.$permalink.'">'. get_the_post_thumbnail() . get_the_title().'</a></div>';
                    $counter++;
                }
            }
            wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </div>
        <?php
        $counter_2 = 1;
        $feat_query_2 = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 5,'meta_key'=>'_thumbnail_id') );

        if ( $feat_query_2->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $feat_query_2->have_posts() ) {
                $feat_query_2->the_post();
                echo '<a class="button '.$counter_2.'" href="#'.$counter_2.'">'.get_the_title().'</a>';
                $counter_2++;
            }
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
    </div>
</section>
```

Be careful not to repeat your variables, that won't work (since they are object actually, you want them to have different names). Also only reset postdata after each query, not the query itself. That way you are only resetting the global `$post` variable of the main query loop. `wp_reset_query()` restores the `$wp_query` and global post data to the original main query, and this isn't affected here.

`WP_Query` is actually a class, and with your query you are actually creating an object from which you can pull out all the necessary data you need. The `wp_reset_query()` and `wp_reset_postdata()` are the methods of the `WP_Query` class that will enable you to use it multiple times without affecting it globally.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer dingo_d

Comment: Use `posts_per_page => 5` instead. The counter on the item div should follow the 1,2,3,4,5. The button one, as it is written will not. I'll edit the code.

Comment: You can also upvote the question, and delete the bottom ones (before you've edited the original to include them) :)